# Is there any algorithmic approach to fit polynomial function like numpy polyfit for x = y^2?

Tags: python, numpy

```
def getPolynomialFitFunction(points):
    # get x and y vectors
    x = points[:,0]
    y = points[:,1]

    # calculate polynomial
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
    f = np.poly1d(z)

    # calculate new x's and y'sq
    x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 3)
    y_new = f(x_new)

    plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
    plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
    plt.show()

    return f

def main():
    arr = []

    for i in range(0, 20):
        arr.append([pow(i,2), -i])
    for i in range(0, 20):
        arr.append([pow(i,2), i])
    
    arr = np.array(arr)
    f = getPolynomialFitFunction(arr)
    print(f(19*19))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have written a python script. I fed the polyfit function with parabola of x = y^2 . The result is very disappointing. Output is here https://ibb.co/0Br8mBj . The main problem is that polyfit() is not good for this occasion. The second one is must be a two output for single x value. For example, if you give value of 5 to x, y will get 5 and -5.  I need to find the polynom and get two y output value for one x input.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you are not trying to find `y=f(x)` here. Or if you do, well, the `y` you got is indeed the best estimation. I mean, if x=100, then y is either +10 or -10. So, 0 is a as good estimation as it can be. And same goes for all other x.

So, it is quite strange to use polyfit to find a polynomial of variable x in the values y, when what you want is to find a polynomial of variable y in the values x.
And it is strange to test the result with `y_new = f(x_new)`. I mean, no offense, but what were you expecting?
What `y=f(x)` would be the expected answer?

So, either you are trying to find the best polynomial that fit the inverse function (namely, `y=√x`) of your input function. In which case you can't feed it with 2 values for the same x. You have to choose which of the 2 branches you are interested in)

Or, you are just trying to find the best polynomial `x=P(y)` that fit `x=y²` (that is, you expect, in this case, to confirm that it is, indeed, `x=y²`). In which case, y is your variable, and x the result (either input, or simulated for testing)

```py
def getPolynomialFitFunction(points):
    # get x and y vectors
    x = points[:,0]
    y = points[:,1]

    # calculate polynomial
    z = np.polyfit(y, x, 2)
    f = np.poly1d(z)

    # calculate new x's and y'sq
    y_new = np.linspace(-y[-1], y[-1], 30)
    x_new = f(y_new)

    plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
    plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
    plt.show()

    return f
```

(Note that I also replaced the 3 by 30, because with 3 you'll have 2 segments)

[image: Result of this code]